# IdentityServer4 - Failed to validate the token

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

**Hello**

Today i'm starting with IdentityServer4, i would like to start a ASP.NET Core 2.2 Site with IdentityServer4 and i ConsoleClient (later an Xamarin Client). But i am desperate it doesnt work. Hope someone can help me.

**I get the following error when i try to call a web api controller from the ConsoleClient  to the ASP.NET site.**

Best regards

```
[02:50:17 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler
Failed to validate the token.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '[PII is hidden]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: '[PII is hidden]' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: '[PII is hidden]'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateAudience(IEnumerable`1 audiences, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) in C:\agent2\_work\56\s\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens\Validators.cs:line 108
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateTokenPayload(JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) in C:\agent2\_work\56\s\src\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt\JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs:line 737
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken) in C:\agent2\_work\56\s\src\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt\JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs:line 719
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()

[02:50:17 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler
BearerIdentityServerAuthenticationJwt was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '[PII is hidden]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: '[PII is hidden]' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: '[PII is hidden]'.

[02:50:17 Information] IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler
Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '[PII is hidden]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: '[PII is hidden]' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: '[PII is hidden]'.

[02:50:17 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler
AuthenticationScheme: BearerIdentityServerAuthenticationJwt was challenged.

[02:50:17 Information] IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
```

Here is my **Config.cs**:

```
namespace IdentityServer
{
    public static class Config
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
        {
            return new IdentityResource[]
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId()
            };
        }

        public static List<TestUser> GetUsers()
        {
            return new List<TestUser>
    {
        new TestUser
        {
            SubjectId = "1",
            Username = "alice",
            Password = "password"
        },
        new TestUser
        {
            SubjectId = "2",
            Username = "bob",
            Password = "bob"
        }
    };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApis()
        {
            return new List<ApiResource>
            {
                new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
            };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "client",

                RequireConsent = false,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

                // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,

                // secret for authentication
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },

                // scopes that client has access to
                AllowedScopes = { "api1" }
            }
        };
        }
    }
}
```

My **Startup.cs**:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; }

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment environment)
        {
            Environment = environment;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services
               .AddMvcCore()
               .AddJsonFormatters()
               .AddAuthorization();

            services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                    {
                        options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                        options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                        options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                        options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                        options.IssuerUri = "http://localhost:5000";
                    }
                )
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddJwtBearerClientAuthentication()
                .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());

            services.AddAuthentication()
           .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(o =>
           {
               o.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
               o.ApiName = "client";
               o.ApiSecret = "secret";
               o.EnableCaching = true;
               o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
               o.SaveToken = true;
           }).AddCookie();


            services.AddCors();

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(policy =>
            {
                policy.WithOrigins(
                    "http://localhost:5000",
                    "http://localhost:5001");

                policy.AllowAnyHeader();
                policy.AllowAnyMethod();
                policy.WithExposedHeaders("WWW-Authenticate");
            });

            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
    }
```

Sample **Auth. Controller**:

```
[Route("api/identity")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public class IdentityController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            //return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
            return new OkObjectResult("OK");
        }
    }
```

Sample **Client Console App**:

```
class Program
    {
        static HttpClient _tokenClient = new HttpClient();
        static DiscoveryCache _cache = new DiscoveryCache("http://localhost:5000");

        static async Task Main()
        {
            Console.Title = "Console ResourceOwner Flow UserInfo";

            var response = await RequestTokenAsync();
            response.Show();

            await CallServiceAsync(response.AccessToken);
        }

        static async Task CallServiceAsync(string token)
        {
            var baseAddress = "http://localhost:5000";

            var client = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress)
            };

            client.SetBearerToken(token);
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync("api/identity");

        }

        static async Task<TokenResponse> RequestTokenAsync()
        {
            var disco = await _cache.GetAsync();
            if (disco.IsError) throw new Exception(disco.Error);

            var response = await _tokenClient.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
            {
                Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,

                ClientId = "client",
                ClientSecret = "secret",                

                UserName = "bob",
                Password = "bob",

                Scope = "api1"
            });

            if (response.IsError) throw new Exception(response.Error);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `startup.cs.` you would need to set your `ApiName` to `api1` based on your `ApiResource` config:

```
       .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(o =>
       {
           ...
           o.ApiName = "api1";
           ...
       }).AddCookie();
```